# "It helps me understand", "It helps me to understand" or "it helps me understanding"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct:
1)It helps me understand
2)It helps me to understand
3)it helps me understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are correct and mean the same thing. The third is wrong. "Understanding" in that case is a gerund (a present participle acting as a noun) and so requires a possessive to indicate which person's understanding is meant. So we need a possessive pronoun.

> It helps my understanding

is also correct and has the same meaning as the others.